# Unable to delete a subnet in my resourcegroup

Tags: azure

When i am trying to delete the subnet from my Resource group I am getting this error.

`Failed to delete subnet 'app_subnet'. Error: Subnet app_subnet is in use.`

This subnet was left after I tried clearing all the deployment in my resourcegroup which was an app service.

Able to remove the subnet so I can delete the resourcegroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below mentioned workaround.

1. Create App Service Plan with the same name as the deleted one
2. Create App Service with the same name as the deleted one
3. Link App Service with the VNET subnet
4. Disconnect VNet from App Service -> Networking -> VNet integration -> Disconnect
5. Delete subnet

Additionally you can also create a ticket to Azure Support via "Help & Support" to get it deleted.